# Problem with "log(0)" error while using brms in R to do Bayesian analysis

Tags: r, bayesian, hierarchical-bayesian, stan

I'm using `brms` to conduct a multilevel regression in R.  I've been getting warnings and errors of the following type:

```
Rejecting initial value:
  Log probability evaluates to log(0), i.e. negative infinity.
  Stan can't start sampling from this initial value.
(many repetitions of the above)

Initialization between (-2, 2) failed after 100 attempts.
```

I've gradually stripped out as much as I could out of the call to the simplest form that still produces the error. I used to include a Gamma family with a log link function, fixed and random effects, narrower priors, more iterations, and more chains.  I've scaled back so that I can identify if the error remains as I remove elements that could conceivably have caused it. (Note that there are very few iterations in this snippet only because I got tired of running the entire thing just to produce the error). This is what remains:

```
fit1 <- brm(formula = newLatency | cens(mycens) ~ (1|participant),
            data = myd1, 
            warmup = 10,
            iter = 50, 
            chains = 1, 
            cores = 1)
```

I've verified that there are no zero values of `newLatency`, and that all participants have data with a mixture of degrees of censoring (between 11% censored and 59% censored). The only thing that will make the error go away is if I drop the "`| cens(mycens)`" part.

I should note that with the full model (with, of course, many more iterations, fixed effects, etc.), it starts with a ton of the "log(0)" statements and then proceeds to run the model anyway, and it gives me reasonable results.  Given that I'm not doing any log transforms, the error must be embedded in the model in the computation of log likelihoods?  If so, how can I track that down?  I'm just nervous about reporting a result of an analysis that started with a bunch of warnings.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you have is that the algorithm for finding starting values for the MCMC sampling fails to find parameter values that give a non-zero (in terms of the precision used in the program) posterior (i.e. both prior and likelihood need to be non-zero). Once you have such values, the sampling would likely proceed without further issues. The general solution for this type of problem is to

1. Check you (or in this case perhaps the developer of the package) have not made a mistake in specifying the model.
2. Ask you algorithm to try for a longer time to find starting values with non-zero likelihood.
3. Explicitly provide starting values. E.g. ask for all random subject effect to be zero initially. If the `brms` package does not allow you to do that, you might have to hand-specify the model in `rstan`, in which case you can definitely do that.